# Git throws out-of-memory error after logoff from the server

Tags: github, joomla, joomla3.0

I have an issue that I can't seem to be able to solve...

I want to use GutHub to develop a web-app with joomla locally and push my changes to the server everytime I feel like it.
It works great but after I log off the server I get an error that remains, even if I raise the memory limits per config:
**fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed**

I'm not an expert since I'm still starting to use GitHub, but these are my steps and maybe you have an advice for me...

1. (on the 1and1.com server)
   I start on the server, installing a fresh joomla 3.7.4 and copy the .gitignore from git//joomla/joomla-cms into my webroot-directory, ignoring all core files.
2. (server)

   - `git init`
   - `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch false`
   - `cat << EOF >> webrootdir/.git/hooks/post-receive`
   - `#!/bin/sh`
   - `GIT_WORK_TREE=webrootdir git checkout master -f`
   - `EOF`
   - `chmod 755 webrootdir/.git/hooks/post-receive`
3. (local computer, cloning into local dir called webroot)

   - `git clone ssh://password@account.1and1-data.host/homepages/11/123456789/htdocs/webroot webroot`
4. (local)
   do some work
5. (local)

   - `git add . && git commit -m "Joomla 3.7.4"`
   - `git push`
6. (server)

   - `git checkout -f`

I repeat steps 5 and 6 all day long, it works as expected and the files on the server are being updated everytime I repeat the steps.

When I logoff the server or being logged of after some time, the server locks into the error, no matter if I try to checkout or just call git status.
My biggest files are around 250kB (jpegs), I don't manage databases over git, it's just a template folder I'm working on that's being updated, so I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong :-/

Any advice would be very much appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue with

```
git config --global core.preloadIndex false
```